# How to disable new version notifications?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext4

Whenever I open Sublime Text it throws a pop-up:

> A new version of Sublime Text is available, download now?

How can I disable this check?  My work blocks installing software updates.

[image]

Comment: Can you still download the new versions from [here](https://sublimetext.com/3dev)? We're in the midst of a rapid release cycle, and bugs are being dealt with and new features added all the time, so I'd **highly** recommend staying up to date.

Comment: Yeah there's a workaround but it's tedious so I'd rather update manually. My work whitelist what apps you can run as administrator, but the whitelist includes cmd!

Comment: Unregistered versions cannot disable update check.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Go to **Preferences** -> **Settings-User** and add there: `"update_check": false`

**EDIT :**

If it's not working then add this line `127.0.0.1 www.sublimetext.com` in your host file

**File Location**

**Windows :** `c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`

**Linux :** `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Works in 3124 (Ubuntu)

Comment: The preferences setting appears to only work for paid versions. See https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1206 . The host file change works fine for me in 3126 (on Mint) though.

Comment: Works in Windows 10 with Sublime 3 via hosts file.

Answer (score 18):

Preferences / Settings - user

```
{
"update_check": false
}
```

Comment: Not for me it isn't.

Comment: i added -> "update_check": false <- to the right side file. there are two files when you click settings. left side says : // Place your settings in the file "Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings",
// which overrides the settings in here. .So i did and i think it works.

Answer (score 5):

How about you block Sublime Text's connection via firewall? Create a **new rule**.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

*For* **Sublime Text 3 Or Sublime 4 Latest Build - Build 4113 |  BUILD 4121**

*GoTo* **Preferences -> Settings**

*and **Add** Below Line in **Right Side Window Panel Of Sublime Text** and **Save It.***

```
{
    "update_check": false,
}
```

[image]

Comment: Works in ( Windows ) SublimeText - 4113 Build

Answer (score 2):

Some linux distros are update intensive, others fall behind. And this nag is really annoying.

I've disabled the update nag by blocking the entire Sublime domain, thus the app can't check the latest version, thus no update nag.

Just add the line below to the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 www.sublimetext.com
```

Windows: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts

Mac/Linux: /etc/hosts

Note: **Remember that** you (or any other app) won't be able to access the Sublime website while this line is in the hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

Create a outbound rule in firewall for sublime_text.exe